# Adding the Xcode application into Github

Tags: iphone, xcode, github

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In XCode 4 how do I add a remote GitHub repository to an existing local project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803768/in-xcode-4-how-do-i-add-a-remote-github-repository-to-an-existing-local-project)

I want to add my application created on Xcode into Github .I created repository and committed the changes successfully through Xcode but when I push the code on repository it shows following message:
The remote must be online and reachable for push operation to succeed .
Repository is offline.Please give me solution on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create an ssh key locally and add it to your github account?

Here are instructions:

http://help.github.com/mac-set-up-git/