# Xcode: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: objective-c, xcode, git, bitbucket

I am trying to connect Xcode with Git (Bitbucket).

I read this question/"tutorial": 
[In XCode 4 how do I add a remote GitHub repository to an existing local project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803768/in-xcode-4-how-do-i-add-a-remote-github-repository-to-an-existing-local-project/15610960#15610960)

I follow all steps but I have a problem.

In Xcode 4.6.1 I always obtain this error:

"fatal "my_Repo" does not appear to be a git repository fatal: Could not read from remote repository."

What can I do?  I am very noob with XCode.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually linked to the Bitbucket url you are using for your remote repo.

I prefer using at first an https url (not a git one, or an ssh one), as listed in [this BitBucket doc page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git):

```
https://accountname@bitbucket.org/accountname/reponame.git
```

Make sure your repo name and user name are correct, including their case.

> The problem is on Xcode, at the moment to make the "Push". Xcode always shows: "Commit or discard the changes and try again." And isn´t true, there aren´t changes

As in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11910676/6309), you need to add and commit at least one change in order to be able to push.

The [OP Kaisser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1298235/kaisser) [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15612742/xcode-could-not-read-from-remote-repository/15612854?noredirect=1#comment22177588_15612854) this tutorial "**[12 steps to using GitHub with XCode 4](http://www.mindthe.net/devices/2011/04/28/12-steps-to-using-github-with-xcode-4/)**".
What he did was:

> create an empty project and make the commit and the push, all OK.
>   Then, I copied my current project and renamed it

Comment: Also, make sure your project is under source control.

Comment: Hello all. The url is right and ... I will search in google how to verify that my project is under source control. Thanks

Comment: @Kaisser any change for us to see what url you did use? And which step exactly is the one causing your error message?

Comment: Hi VonC, I can´t understand you very well   :(     I have the repo on Bitbucket and I can do commit with console.    The problem is with XCode. When I try to make a "Push" Xcode always shows an error: "Commit or discard the changes and try again."    :S

Comment: @Kaisser what is the url you are using for your repo on BitBucket? What step is causing problem?

Comment: The repo is: https://thefactbitbucket@bitbucket.org/thefactbitbucket/pruebaxcode.git

And the problem is on Xcode, at the moment to make the "Push".
Xcode always shows: "Commit or discard the changes and try again."   And isn´t true, there aren´t changes

Comment: Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910228/cannot-push-pull-or-merge-git-working-copy-has-uncommited-changes?rq=1

Comment: @Kaisser so you need to add and commit first with XCode, *then* push.

Comment: Yes VonC, I can make the "commit" with this steps:   Step 0:  git status
Step 1: git rm --cached ProjectName.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/username.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
Step 2: git commit -m "Removed file that shouldn't be tracked"
    But, now I obtain another problem:  "fatal: 'WTF_App' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists"   Is the problem that I talked in my first question.    How can I solve it? Thanks!

Comment: @Kaisser What does `git remote -v` returns? and `git branch --all`?

Comment: git remote -v returns nothing and git branch --all * master.   What means? :/    Thanks!

Comment: @Kaisser That means you are on the `master` branch (which is good), but git push wouldn't know *where* to push to, since no remote is registered. Try, as in https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BBKB/fatal%3A+'origin'+does+not+appear+to+be+a+git+repository, to add a remote origin: `git remote add origin https://thefactbitbucket@bitbucket.org/thefactbitbucket/pruebaxcode.git`

Comment: @Kaisser is `WTF_App` directory is in the `pruebaxcode` directory? You need to have `pruebaxcode` cloned locally and version `WTF_App` directory in it, for `WTF_App` to be in a git repository.

Comment: I think I have problems with directories.  What´s the right sctructure?.  I will try to do a test-project and connect to my repository.  Thanks

Comment: @Kaisser If you clone a repo `pruebaxcode`, you must see a `pruebaxcode/.git`. Any project supposed to be in source control should be `pruebaxcode` directory or sub-directory.

Comment: Solved!   I follow this tutorial step by step:  http://www.mindthe.net/devices/2011/04/28/12-steps-to-using-github-with-xcode-4/   I create an empty project and make the commit and the push, all OK. Then, I copied my current project and renamed it.  THANKS!

Comment: @Kaisser Excellent. I have included your link in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing a similar issue, starting today. I haven't made any commits or pushes to my BitBucket repo in about 2 months, but I never had issues before. XCode is now telling me that the repository "could not be reached" and to "Please verify that the repository is online and reachable and try again". I can commit from the command line. I wonder if this is an XCode 4.6.1 bug?

PS - not sure if I put this in the right place. I've never posted on SO. Correct me if I did this wrong!

Comment: Welcome! Because Stack Overflow is for questions and answers, try upvoting the question to show interest and support. Then you can leave more information as a comment below the question. Right now, you have left this as an answer to the problem. :)