# How to use sourcetree between two developers?

Tags: version-control

We are two people working on same project but it is difficult to merge it when we both make changes to it.Now I come to know that I can use Bitbucket and Source tree to tackle this problem.I have tried using Bitbucket and source tree but it is not working.I thing I am doing something wrong here.......
   So if anybody is having idea about this please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: For one, create branches and work on individual branches if working on different problems. If working on the same issue, maybe take shifts? Or try to divide the work (and branch)?

Comment: Which IDE your Using

Comment: @Anil Meenugu  Xcode 6.2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803768/in-xcode-4-how-do-i-add-a-remote-github-repository-to-an-existing-local-project

Answer (score 0):

Whether you’re a solo developer or working on a team, if you’re not using source control for your projects, you should be.
Source control is amazing because it helps you more easily revert to older version of your code, see how your code has changed over time, and work as a team. And one of the best source control systems is built right into Xcode – git!

For furthur info

http://www.raywenderlich.com/13771/how-to-use-git-source-control-with-xcode-in-ios-6

Answer (score 0):

Using Bitbucket in Source tree is really a grate idea. But it is very systematic. 
Please follow the below link. It will help you to solve your team work.

For Concept:

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow

For Practical Use:

https://github.com/GSoft-SharePoint/Dynamite/wiki/Getting-started-with-SourceTree,-Git-and-git-flow